Diferencia significativa en el uso de memoria CUDA entre el éxito y el fracaso de la inferencia de un modelo PyTorch con datos de entrada fijos
He encontrado un problema de memoria CUDA al inferir un modelo PyTorch sobre datos de entrada de tamaño fijo ([128, 1, 512]).
Si sólo hago una predicción en un archivo, la inferencia falla y me devuelven estos valores:
pData.size(): torch.Size([128, 1, 512])
torch.cuda.memory_allocated(): 357376
torch.cuda.memory_reserved(): 2097152

Y en el caso en el que predigo para una carpeta de archivos, la inferencia tiene éxito, y obtengo estos valores :
pData.size(): torch.Size([128, 1, 512])
torch.cuda.memory_allocated(): 358400
torch.cuda.memory_reserved(): 44040192

Este es el error que obtengo cuando hago una sola predicción en un archivo:
...
x.size: torch.Size([128, 1, 512])
x.size: torch.Size([128, 1, 512])
x: tensor([[[0.54997, 0.52163, 0.19563,  ..., 0.34677, 0.23625, 0.21865]],
...
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 20.00 MiB (GPU 0; 7.78 GiB total capacity; 10.22 MiB already allocated; 1.19 MiB free; 22.00 MiB reserved in total by PyTorch)

Y aquí está la salida cuando navego por todos los archivos de una carpeta:
...
x.size: torch.Size([128, 1, 512])
x.size: torch.Size([128, 1, 512])
x: tensor([[[0.4228, 0.4436, 0.3818,  ..., 0.1387, 0.1879, 0.1545]],
...
Y_pred.shape: (4986,) Y.shape: (4986,)

El código utilizado para predecir todos los archivos de una carpeta es el siguiente:
model = UC_Model(pModel_filepath="/mnt/confiance/common/UC_Data_Folder/UC_Anomaly_Detection/models/trained_perceiver/best_model_spectra")
(X, Y, X_val, Y_val), (l_data_X, l_data_Y) = model.prepareData(
    pDataPath="/mnt/confiance/common/UC_Data_Folder/UC_Anomaly_Detection/Dataset/test_bench_data/")
X = np.transpose(X, (0, 2, 1))
X_val = np.transpose(X, (0, 2, 1))
print("X.shape: ", X.shape)
print("Y.shape: ", Y.shape)
X_LENGTH = len(X) 
with torch.no_grad():
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    loss = 0
    Y_pred = np.zeros(np.shape(Y))
    for i in range(X_LENGTH // BATCH_SIZE):
        x = torch.from_numpy(
            X[i * BATCH_SIZE:(i + 1) * BATCH_SIZE]
        ).float().to(DEVICE)
        print("x.size: ", x.size())
        print("x.size: ", x.size())
        y = torch.from_numpy(
            Y[i * BATCH_SIZE:(i + 1) * BATCH_SIZE]
        ).long().to(DEVICE)
        x = x.to(DEVICE)
        y_ = model(x)
        y_ = y_.cpu().argmax(dim=-1)
        total += len(y_)
        print("y_.size: ", y_.size(), " y.size(): ", y.size())
        correct += (y_ == y.cpu()).sum().item()
        Y_pred[i * BATCH_SIZE:(i + 1) * BATCH_SIZE] = y_
plot_confusion_matrix(Y, Y_pred, anomaly_list)
print("Y_pred.shape: ", Y_pred.shape, "Y.shape: ", Y.shape)

Y el código para procesar un único fichero es el siguiente:
def UC_computeInference(pAiModel,pDictParams):
    pNbData=pDictParams['nbData']
    pClasses=pDictParams['classes']
    pDataPathList=pDictParams['dataPathList']
    pDataProd=pDictParams['dataProd']
    pRepertProd=pDictParams['repertProd']
    pSauvegarde=pDictParams['backup']=="oui"
    pListObjets=pDictParams['objets']
    pDataList=pDictParams['dataList']
    listInferError=[]
    x_test=[]
    y_pred=[]
    for i in range(pNbData):
        dataPreprocessed=pAiModel.prepareData(pDataPathList[i])
        prediction=pAiModel(dataPreprocessed)

En todos los casos, se trata de la función utilizada para inicializar y llamar al modelo:
class UC_Model:
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ## Fonction d'initialisation du modèle
    # @param pModel_filepath : chemin d'accès du modèle fourni
    # def __init__(self, pModelpath, pModel_filepath, pParams_filepath="perceiver_params.json"):
    def __init__(self, pModel_filepath):

        self.name="UC_Anomaly_Detection"  # le nom du sous-répertoire du use case dans le répertoire des Use Case MODEL_BASE
        self.resPredictionsCibles=[]
        self.resPredictionsSamples=[]
        self.inferenceCible=True

        # Initialize model
        # self.model = create_perceiver_model()

        # Load model
        # /mnt/confiance/common/UC_Data_Folder/UC_Anomaly_Detection/models/trained_perceiver/best_model_spectra 
        self.model = torch.load(pModel_filepath)

    def to_tensor(self, X, Y, i):
        x = torch.from_numpy(
            X[i * BATCH_SIZE:(i + 1) * BATCH_SIZE]
        ).float().to(DEVICE)
        print("x.size: ", x.size()) # x.size:  torch.Size([128, 512, 1]) alors qu'il faut x.size:  torch.Size([128, 1, 512])
        x = x.permute(0, 2, 1) # C'est pas grave, on permute 
        print("after permutting: ")
        print("x.size: ", x.size())
        y = torch.from_numpy(
            Y[i * BATCH_SIZE:(i + 1) * BATCH_SIZE]
        ).long().to(DEVICE)
        x = x.to(DEVICE)
        
        return x, y

    ## Fonction d'appel du modèle
    # @param pData : données/samples à traiter
    # @return resultat d'inférence
    def __call__(self, pData):
        print("pData.size(): ", pData.size())
        print("torch.cuda.memory_allocated(): ", torch.cuda.memory_allocated())
        print("torch.cuda.memory_reserved(): ", torch.cuda.memory_reserved())
        # Run the Perceiver on the model
        z = self.model.perceiver(pData)
    
        # Pass through linear layers
        z = self.model.linear1(z)
        z = z.mean(dim=0)
        z = self.model.linear2(z)
        return F.log_softmax(z, dim=-1)

